# How to copy javascript variables/objects from one file to another file

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, react-native, automation

I am trying to separate in-file CSS from the code and create separate file for the CSS in my react-native project. Instead of having the styles variable in the same file, I want to put it in another component.style.js file and import it from there.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native' 

export default class Component extends React.Component{
    render(){
        {some component}
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:"center",
        backgroundColor:'red'
    },
    block:{
        backgroundColor:'green',
        height:200,
        width:200,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    }
});
```

The issue is the project has way too many components to do it manually. I want to somehow automate this task. For any file abc.js, I want to create abc.style.js, cut the styles variable from this file, paste it in abc.styles.js and import it in abc.js

Is there any way to **automate** the whole creating, copying and importing process using python, node.js or any other libraries?

I would prefer to use a method better than brute force method like read file using python, get starting and ending point, copy the strings, paste it. Is there an easy, efficient and quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style file that matches your files.

**Example**  **styles.js**

```js
import { Dimensions, Platform } from "react-native";

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const windoWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    height: Platform.OS === "ios" ? windowHeight : undefined,
    width: Platform.OS === "ios" ? windoWidth : undefined,
  }
...
```

**Example** **Usage**

```js
import styles from "./styles.js";
...
<View style={styles.container}>
```

Comment: This is fine, but is there anyway to automate this task? I don't want to do this manually for all the files. There are around 50-60 js files and this process needs to be done for all of them.

Comment: @r-arvind Ah... I couldn't read the whole question. Currently, there is no module that automatically sets the style. If you can make it, it will be a great revolution.